# json data not displaying in html

Tags: php, mysql, json

The below is the file to show data retrieved from database using php.

```
<table class="mGrid" id="jsondata">
<thead>
<th>rollno</th>
<th>student name</th>
<th>branch</th>

</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var url="getjson.php";
$("#jsondata tbody").html("");
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.users, function(i,user){
var newRow =
"<tr>"
+"<td>"+user.rollno+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.stuname+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.branch+"</td>"

+"</tr>" ;
$(newRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
});
});
});

</script>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

The code for fetching data from mysql

```
</p>
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "root";
$mysql_db_password = "neel";
$mysql_db_database = "sitams";



$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password,
 $mysql_db_database);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$var = array();
 $sql = "SELECT rollno,stuname,branch FROM studet where year='i' and academic='2014-2015'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$var[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"users":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
<p style="text-align: justify;">
```

I can see the results in getjson.php but could not able to see showjson.html what is the reason.

Comment: The `.getJSON()` function is expecting to receive JSON data.  But your `getjson.php` responds with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to validate the json provided by your page with an online service ? (jsonlint, jsonparser, and son on ??)

If your JSON is not valid, you won't be able to decode it.

Furthermore, can you access the data from

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data)
```

in your browser console.

My guess is you have a problem in this json.

HTH